# If a user delivers a file as input for a use case, what is the actor : the user or the file

Tags: uml, use-case

Our call center collects requests from customer, which are processed by back office. Much of the requests are passed in spreadsheets by type of request.
In view of automating some work of back office, I want to model the current situation. How do I proceed?

- Do I model the call center as an actor, and the describe spreadsheet as an interface between that actor and the use case
- Or do I model the spreadsheat itself as an actor? (After all, applications can be actors, right?)

Edit:
It is a requirement not to change the task of the call center, so the spreadsheet is a given and the main use case is to process the requests listed in that specific spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

Actors should generally be people, or rather the business role the person is in.

Applications can be actors, but normally this is when they are doing something like a scheduled task. Ie. behaving like a person doing a job.

In your case the spreadsheet only really comes into the use case if its part of the requirements that a spreadsheet be used. for example if your project is:

> "Automate collecting the spreadsheets from the email folder and
>   putting them in the database"

Then the use case should have spreadsheets mentioned in there, as they are an unchangeable and critical part of any system developed.

On the other hand if the project is:

> "Automate getting the customer request into the database"

Then maybe you shouldn't have the spreadsheets in at all. Clearly they are simply the current format used for passing the message and its the fact that the message is passed that is important. Not the format used. Indeed your project probably wouldn't use spreadsheets, replacing them with a web page or something sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

On black-box level your actors are `Customer` and `Organization`. If you dive a level deeper to white-box you can break down organization into individual roles and they will become actors.

Why it's important? Organizations change, processes change. Right now it is a call center with the spreadsheet, in two months - it could be a web form or anything. Keep the *business process* separate from its *implementation*.

---

> If a user delivers a file as input for a use case, what is the actor : the user or the file

The user since it performs the action, the file itself literally can't act.

You might also find useful to have two black-box level uses cases like:

- Operator logs in a customer request
- Manager processes a customer request

To separate areas of responsibility and steps of asynchronous process.

Comment: I share your concern, @Vlad, named my actor Front Office and doccumented as (currently) being the Customer Service department and mentioned the excel file as the way front office communicates requests..